Book recommendation of complex analysis in several variables
I want to learn complex analysis. I would like a book that teaches about complex analysis in several variables without assuming that the reader knows complex analysis in one variable.
The only book I found that do this is the book “Foundations of Modern Analysis” by J. Dieudonné. However this book is very difficult to read, so I want to find another book.
Which book teaches complex analysis in several variables without assuming that the reader knows complex analysis in one variable?

I don't know much about the topic, but I doubt you'll find such a book unless it's like Dieudonné in that it would require a very high level of mathematical sophistication. All the books on several complex variables I recall coming across in university libraries over the past 5 decades essentially assume the reader has studied single-variable complex analysis, probably because I doubt there is much of a market or need for such a book. Alternatively, maybe some expository writing by Steven G. Krantz, such as this paper, or a survey article in Bull. AMS.

It is not a good idea to try to learn complex analysis in several variables before you learn complex analysis in one variable. It's the same as trying to learn multivariable calculus before you learn single variable calculus. This is even more so if you find Dieudonné's book very difficult. Please focus first on learning complex analysis in one variable really really well first.

Also, Dieudonné's book is not on complex analysis in several variables. It is an advanced text on real analysis. To learn complex variables in several variables, you definitely need to know a lot of what's in that book. But it's probably not the right book to study from. See, for example, this: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/5686
